# ArcGIS AddIn with WPF DockableWindow causes ArcMap to not even start up anymore

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, add-in, wpf

I have a simple ArcGIS AddIn with a toolbar and a button on it, which opens a DockableWindow holding a UserControl with some UI Elements on it (a textbox and a listbox). The whole thing was made with the ArcGIS VisualStudio Integration Wizard with the "Windows Forms" Designer type and working as expected.

Now I wanted to port this to WPF Designer type because of improvements in data binding and so on. So I fired up ArcGIS VS Wizard again and created a new DockableWindow with WPF. In Config.esriaddinx I changed the config to point to the new WPF Control instead of the Windows Forms Control, just to test if it works (no more functionality implemented yet).

But when I start ArcMap now, it immediately crashes and Visual Studio Output Windows tells me

```
The program '[6296] ArcMap.exe: Managed (v2.0.50727)' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

Nothing more there to pin down the reason for this. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I know it's a very long time ago, but do you remember ever having found a solution? I seem to be having the same problem.